# Organize Java Imports programmatically

Tags: java, android, import, preprocessor

I have written a custom build script for my android app. I included some "easy" preprocessing, so I can define comments like

```
//#ifdef something
... CODE
//#endif
```

and get rid of the Code part if configured so. The Problem is, that after preprocessing I don't need some modules anymore, so I leave them out. What remains is the import statement for that module which bites me, if I want to build the app finally. I'm searching for a way within my preprocessing, to organize the java Imports inside my script after preprocessing happens. Any Solution without the need for additional "clicks" is very welcome.

Comment: There's no significant penalty for the additional imports if the library you're importing from is used somewhere else in the app. That said, the whole notion of pre-processor in Java code seems like an altogether bad idea.

Comment: @corsiKa there is **no** runtime penalty for additional imports. Imports are only processed during compile time.

Comment: @Steve there's no **significant** compile time penalty *if the library is used elsewhere*. The only real significant penalty for additional imports is loading the libraries into the compiler. Actually using them in an import statement is very low. So if an import statement is no longer needed in one file, but the library it comes from is needed in another file, there is no significant compile time increase for leaving the import statement in.

Comment: Youre all right. The problem here is that the library isn't used elsewhere, so that I dide not even copy the sources of it into the project. Therefore the compilation breaks, because it has an import, the compiler could not find any classes for it

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you're really need preprocessor (quite rare). But you could actually achieve same goal with right build process.

Anyway back to the question you could use next technique:

```
//#ifdef something
... IMPORTS
//#endif
```

Comment: shure, this is good as long as some dev didn't make an "organizeImports" which will in fact remove the comments in the imports

Answer (score 0):

take a look at http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/
p.s.
example of usage for one of my cases
http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/wiki/ExampleOfUsageForJ2ME